# How does TeXbook macro \stest work?

Tags: tex-core, texbook.tex

Let's put the `\stest` macro from TeXbook to file `stest.tex` with some
formatting and adding line numbers for reference.

```
 1  \newif\ifspace \newif\iffunny \newif\ifexplicit \newif\ifactive
 2  \def\stest#1{
 3    \funnyfalse
 4    \expandafter\s\the#1! \stest}
 5  \def\s{
 6    \global\explicitfalse
 7    \global\activefalse
 8    \futurelet\next\ss}
 9  \def\ss{
10    \ifcat\noexpand\next\stoken
11      \let\nxt\sx
12    \else
13      \let\nxt\ns
14    \fi
15    \nxt}
16  \def\sx{
17    \spacetrue
18    \ifx\next\stoken
19      \let\nxt\sss
20    \else
21      \let\nxt=\ssss
22    \fi
23    \nxt}
24  \long\def\sss#1 #2\stest{
25    \def\next{#1}
26    \ifx\next\empty
27      \global\explicittrue
28    \else
29      \testactive#1\s
30    \fi}
31  \long\def\ssss#1#2\stest{
32    \funnytrue
33    \begingroup
34      \escapechar=\if*#1`?\else`*\fi\relax
35      \if#1\string#1
36        \uccode`#1=`~ % we assume that ~ is an active character
37        \uppercase{\ifcat\noexpand#1}\noexpand~
38          \global\activetrue
39        \else
40          \global\explicittrue
41        \fi
42      \else
43        \testactive#1\s
44      \fi
45    \endgroup}
46  \long\def\ns#1\stest{
47    \spacefalse}
48  \long\def\testactive#1#2\s{
49    \expandafter\tact\string#1\s\tact}
50  \long\def\tact#1#2\tact{
51    \def\next{#2}
52    \ifx\next\xs
53      \global\activetrue
54    \else
55      \ifx\next\empty
56        \global\activetrue
57      \fi
58    \fi}
59  \def\xs{\s}
\def\\{\let\stoken= } \\
\def\report{
  \ifspace\message{SPACE}\fi
  \iffunny\message{FUNNY}\fi
  \ifexplicit\message{EXPLICIT}\fi
  \ifactive\message{ACTIVE}\fi}
```

Comment: but as a new edition of the texbook has a different macro, why do you correct the old one?

Comment: I agree the uppercase looks spurious but to count as a bug you would need to show the version in the post 1991 editions actually gives a wrong answer, not just that it could be optimised a bit.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko I won't retract my downvote until you remove “nonsense”, which is utterly offensive.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko I have posted three issues with your suggested variant in my answer.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko see my answer where an active `+` is made an implicit space token, your version reports it as a normal space, the texbook reports it as an active character.

Comment: Uhm, with your edits you have completely changed the question, thus making the existing answers pointless.

Comment: @campa They helped me to understand the subject in more depth and that means that they are useful

Comment: This is vandalizing your own post.

Comment: @egreg For one who searches understanding how `\stest` works my post is perfect

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Possibly, but it's not the same question you posted originally. You should remove your self-answer, restore the previous version and make a different post.

Comment: @egreg please say exactly what parts of my answer contain errors

Comment: @IgorLiferenko I claimed nothing about errors in your self-answer. But it answers a ***different*** question than originally posted. Changing a question so as to invalidate existing answers is not among the accepted policies of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Overview:**

• An implicit space can be an active character (which is called “active” here; we must separate “active
space” from “active space-token”) or a control sequence.

• In \ss we branch catcode 10 or not.

• In \sx we branch beween normal and funny.

• In \sss we branch between explicit and active/implicit.

• In \ssss we branch between active/explicit and active/implicit.

• In \testactive we branch between active and implicit.

• Parameter text for \sss is #1 #2 because: if first token in token list is explicit space, it is matched to
the space in parameter text and hence #1 will be empty. On the other hand, if the first token in token
list is implicit space or active space, an explicit space in the token list (if there is one — not in the first
position) or the space after the ! (if there is no explicit space in token list) is matched to the space in
parameter text, and #1 will include all tokens in the stream before the explicit space.

• Each space token (if it is the first in token list) is handled via two separate routes. In the first route
(via \futurelet, which makes \next an implicit space token, regardless whether the space token is
explicit/implicit/active) we detect catcode 10 in line 10. In the second route (via argument #1 to
macros \sss and \ssss, which leaves each space token intact) we detect explicit/implicit/active.

• In line 37 we branch between active and explicit. There is a subtlety: we use \uppercase to turn the
active character from implicit space into a macro, to prevent substituting the active character with what
is inside of it, during the \ifcat test (~ is a macro by default).

• For ACTIVE there are two cases (let's assume that active character is `+'):

[a] + → normal

[b] + → funny

There are two more special cases:

[c] charcode of active character is 32 (this case may be split into two sub-cases: when the space, that
is inside the active character, has charcode 32; and when charcode is not 32).

[d] charcode of active character and charcode, which is inside of the active character, are the same
(they must not be equal to 32 — this is a sub-case of [c]; and they must not be equal to 126 — it
is used in line 37).

• Argument list for \tact is formed by running \string on the first token in token list (it is assumed
that \escapechar is between 0 and 255). If this token is not active, there will be two or more tokens
in arument list. If this token is an active character with charcode not 32, there will be one token in
argument list; if this token is an active character with charcode 32, argument list will be empty. \tact
detects these two cases in order to determine whether the token is active.

• We change \escapechar in line 34 in order that it cannot be equal to charcode of space (explicit or
inside of active and implicit) — to guarantee that test in line 35 cannot be true for control sequences.

• \long is used in case token list contains \par.

**Examples:**

**0. Output is empty.**

```
\input stest
\newtoks\t
\t={}
\stest\t \report \bye
```

\next is equivalent to !. Test in line 10 is false. In line 46 #1 is ! .

**1. Output is SPACE EXPLICIT**

```
\input stest
\newtoks\t
\t={ }
\stest\t \report \bye
```

We get into \sss. #1 is empty, #2 is ! . Test in line 26 is true.

**2. Output is SPACE FUNNY EXPLICIT**

```
\input stest
{\uccode` =`*\uppercase{\gdef\fspace{ }}}
\newtoks\t
\t=\expandafter{\fspace}
\stest\t \report \bye
```

We get into \ssss. #1 is *, #2 is ! . Test in line 35 is true. Test in line 37 is false.

**3. Output is SPACE**

```
\input stest
\newtoks\t
\t={\stoken}
\stest\t \report \bye
```

We get into \sss. #1 is \stoken!, #2 is empty. Test in line 26 is false. We get into \testactive. #1 is
\stoken, #2 is !. We get into \tact. #1 is , #2 is stoken\s.

**4. Output is SPACE FUNNY**

```
\input stest
{\def\\{\global\let\ftoken= } \uccode` =`*\uppercase{\\ }}
\newtoks\t
\t={\ftoken}
\stest\t \report \bye
```

We get into \ssss. #1 is \ftoken, #2 is ! . Test in line 35 is false. We get into \testactive. #1 is \ftoken,
#2 is empty. We get into \tact. #1 is , #2 is ftoken\s.

**5. Output is SPACE ACTIVE**

```
\input stest
{\uccode`~=` \uppercase{\def\\{\global\let~= }} \\ }
\newtoks\t
{\catcode` =\active \global\t={ }}
\stest\t \report \bye
```

We get into \sss. #1 is !, #2 is empty. Test in line 26 is false. We get into \testactive. #1 is , #2 is !. We get into \tact. #1 is \s, #2 is empty. Test in line 52 is false. Test in line 55 is true.

**6. Output is SPACE ACTIVE**

```
\input stest
{\uccode`~=` \uppercase{\def\\{\global\let~= }} \uccode` =`*\uppercase{\\ }}
\newtoks\t
{\catcode` =\active \global\t={ }}
\stest\t \report \bye
```

We get into \ssss. #1 is , #2 is ! . Test in line 35 is false. We get into \testactive. #1 is , #2 is empty. We get into \tact. #1 is \s, #2 is empty. Test in line 52 is false. Test in line 55 is true.

**7. Output is SPACE ACTIVE**

```
\input stest
{\catcode`+=\active \def\\{\global\let+= } \\ }
\newtoks\t
{\catcode`+=\active \global\t={+}}
\stest\t \report \bye
```

We get into \sss. #1 is +!, #2 is empty. Test in line 26 is false. We get into \testactive. #1 is +, #2 is !.
We get into \tact. #1 is +, #2 is \s. Test in line 52 is true.

**8. Output is SPACE FUNNY ACTIVE**

```
\input stest
{\catcode`+=\active \def\\{\global\let+= } \uccode` =`*\uppercase{\\ }}
\newtoks\t
{\catcode`+=\active \global\t={+}}
\stest\t \report \bye
```

We get into \ssss. #1 is +, #2 is ! . Test in line 35 is false. We get into \testactive. #1 is +, #2 is empty.
We get into \tact. #1 is +, #2 is \s. Test in line 52 is true.

**9. Output is SPACE FUNNY ACTIVE**

```
\input stest
{\catcode`*=\active \def\\{\global\let*= } \uccode` =`*\uppercase{\\ }}
\newtoks\t
{\catcode`*=\active \global\t={*}}
\stest\t \report \bye
```

We get into \ssss. #1 is *, #2 is ! . Test in line 35 is true. Test in line 37 is true.

Answer (score 3):

The suggested replacement has a few problems

- with `\t={}`  it reports `SPACE EXPLICIT`  as a space rather than `!` is used as a guard token. (In comments you suggest that it could be documented, but fixing it would be better)
- with `\t{\par}`  it reports

  ```
  ! Paragraph ended before \next was complete.
  <to be read again> 
                     \par
  ```

  despite your assertion that "`\long` is not necessary""
- After

  ```
  \catcode`\+\active
  \let+= \stoken
  \t{+}
  ```

  Your version reports

  `SPACE`

  But the texbook reports

  `SPACE ACTIVE`

  from

  ```
  \ifspace\message{SPACE}\fi
  \iffunny\message{FUNNY}\fi
  \ifexplicit\message{EXPLICIT}\fi
  \ifactive\message{ACTIVE}\fi
  ```

---

```
% texbook
\catcode`\8=9
\catcode`\9=14


9\message{Igor L}
9\newif\ifactive % extra always false here
9\newif\ifspace \newif\iffunny \newif\ifexplicit
9\def\stest#1{\spacefalse \funnyfalse \explicitfalse \expandafter\s\the#1 \stest}
9\def\s{\futurelet\next\ss}
9\def\ss{\ifcat\noexpand\next\stoken\spacetrue
9    \ifx\next\stoken\let\next=\sss\else\let\next=\ssss\fi
9  \else\let\next=\sssss\fi \next}
9\def\sss#1 #2\stest{\def\next{#1}\ifx\next\empty\explicittrue\fi}
9\def\ssss#1#2\stest{\funnytrue
9  {\escapechar=\if*#1`\?\else`\*\fi \if#1\string#1\global\explicittrue\fi}}
9\def\sssss#1\stest{}


8\message{TeXBook}
8\newif\ifspace \newif\iffunny \newif\ifexplicit \newif\ifactive
8\def\stest#1{\funnyfalse \expandafter\s\the#1! \stest}
8\def\s{\global\explicitfalse \global\activefalse \futurelet\next\ss}
8\def\ss{\ifcat\noexpand\next\stoken\let\nxt\sx\else\let\nxt\ns\fi\nxt}
8\def\sx{\spacetrue\ifx\next\stoken\let\nxt\sss\else\let\nxt=\ssss\fi\nxt}
8\long\def\sss#1 #2\stest{\def\next{#1}%
8  \ifx\next\empty \global\explicittrue \else\testactive#1\s\fi}
8\long\def\ssss#1#2\stest{\funnytrue{\escapechar=\if*#1`?\else`*\fi\relax
8  \if#1\string#1\uccode`#1=`~ % we assume that ~ is an active character
8    \uppercase{\ifcat\noexpand#1}\noexpand~\global\activetrue
8    \else\global\explicittrue\fi
8  \else\testactive#1\s\fi}}
8\long\def\ns#1\stest{\spacefalse}
8\long\def\testactive#1#2\s{\expandafter\tact\string#1\s\tact}
8\long\def\tact#1#2\tact{\def\next{#2}\ifx\next\xs\global\activetrue
8  \else\ifx\next\empty \global\activetrue\fi\fi} \def\xs{\s}






\def\\{\let\stoken= } \\ % now \stoken is a space token
\uccode`\ =`\* \uppercase{\uppercase{\def\fspace{ }\let\ftoken= } }
\catcode`\+\active
\let+= \stoken
\newtoks\t


\immediate\write200{empty}
\t={}
\stest\t
\ifspace\message{SPACE}\fi
\iffunny\message{FUNNY}\fi
\ifexplicit\message{EXPLICIT}\fi
\ifactive\message{ACTIVE}\fi

\immediate\write200{par}
\t={\par}
\stest\t
\ifspace\message{SPACE}\fi
\iffunny\message{FUNNY}\fi
\ifexplicit\message{EXPLICIT}\fi
\ifactive\message{ACTIVE}\fi


\immediate\write200{active plus}
\t={+}
\stest\t
\ifspace\message{SPACE}\fi
\iffunny\message{FUNNY}\fi
\ifexplicit\message{EXPLICIT}\fi
\ifactive\message{ACTIVE}\fi

\bye
```

produces

```
empty
par
active plus
SPACE ACTIVE
```

using the TeXBook code, change to

```
\catcode`\8=14
\catcode`\9=9
```

so it uses the code from the question and it produces

```
empty
SPACE EXPLICIT
par
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \next was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
\stest ...e \explicitfalse \expandafter \s \the #1
                                                   \stest 
l.61 \stest\t
             
? 
! You can't use `\par' after \the.
l.66 
     
? 
Runaway argument?
0
! Paragraph ended before \next was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.67 
     
? 
active plus
SPACE )
```

Comment: But then `\ifcat\noexpand\next\stoken` should be true in `\ss`. How can this happen when category of `+` is 13 and category of `\stoken` is 10?!

Comment: @IgorLiferenko I am just reporting results, so far in all cases where the texbook (post 1991) code gives a different result to the version you suggest, the texbook answer seems right, I leave you to debug your code.

Comment: But I'm asking exactly about TeXbook code in my comment to your answer. 13 can't be equal to 10!

Comment: are you looking at the current texbook, the version you show in your question isn't that relevant, the texbook version post 1991 has a separate test for active character `\testactive` which it does before running `\s` @IgorLiferenko

Comment: I'm looking at current texbook.tex and there `\ss` is called earlier than `\testactive`! Besides, in preface to `\stest` it is said that it is concerned only with space token as defined in Chapter 24. Does your `+` count as such?

Comment: Please put the complete code that you use to the answer

Comment: @IgorLiferenko full test code added as requested

Comment: @IgorLiferenko yes `+` is an implicit space token if it is active and `\let` to a space.

Comment: That's interesting! But how `\ifcat\noexpand\next\stoken` turns out to be true for this `+` ? Why 13 is equal to 10?

Comment: No, wait, according to definition of `\ifcat` in TeXbook, the `+` has catcode 16. So, 16 mysteriously becomes equal to 10...

Comment: @IgorLiferenko implicit characters have the category code of the character

Comment: That active-implicit trick is a whole new phenomenon for me! Please help me to understand what exactly means the following phrase on the definition of `\if` in TeXbook: "unless **the current equivalent** of that control sequence has been **let-equal to non-active** character token"

Comment: BTW, did't Knuth forget to add here "and non-active space token"?

Comment: a space token is a character token. checking for these cases is why the code you called various names is there.

Answer (score 3):

The Knuth's macro code mentioned here is somewhat obscure. The given problem should be solved using more clear macros, IMHO.

I created `\isfoo <token>?\iftrue` macros (exactly one `<token>` must be here). They do all needed tests. You can combine them appropriately in order to get the result of the Knuth's macros.

```
\long\def\isspacetoken #1?\iftrue {\ifcat\space\noexpand#1}
\long\def\iseqspace    #1?\iftrue {\expandafter\ifx\space#1}
\long\def\isspacechar  #1?\iftrue {\if\space\string#1}
\long\def\isactivechar #1?\iftrue {\getccode{#1}\ifnum\ccode=13 }
\long\def\isimplicit  #1#2\iftrue {\ifx?#2\empty}
\def\getccode#1{\expandafter\getccodeA\string#1\\\end}
\def\getccodeA#1#2\end{\expandafter\getccodeB\string\\#1}
\def\getccodeB#1#2#3{\ifx#1#3\chardef\ccode=0 \else\chardef\ccode=\catcode`#3 \fi}

\def\test#1{%
        space token:\isspacetoken #1?\iftrue YES\else no\fi,
        equal space:\iseqspace    #1?\iftrue YES\else no\fi,
    space character:\isspacechar  #1?\iftrue YES\else no\fi,
   active character:\isactivechar #1?\iftrue YES\else no\fi,
     implicit space:\iseqspace    #1?\iftrue 
                    \isimplicit   #1?\iftrue YES\else no\fi\else no\fi.
}

%%% testing:

\def\useit#1{#1}
\useit{\let\stoken= } % \let\stoken= <space> (code 32/10)
\bgroup\lccode`\ =`\* \lowercase{\egroup
   \def\fspace{ }
   \useit{\let\ftoken= } %
}
\catcode`\+\active
\let+= \stoken
\parindent=0pt \hsize=17cm

nomal space   : \test{ }
space token   : \test\stoken
space macro   : \test\space
space token * : \test\ftoken
space macro * : \test\fspace
active space  : \test+
par           : \test\par

\bye
```

The result of testing:

```
nomal space : space token:YES, equal space:YES, space character:no, active character:no, implicit space:no.
space token : space token:YES, equal space:YES, space character:no, active character:no, implicit space:YES.
space macro : space token:no, equal space:no, space character:no, active character:no, implicit space:no.
space token * : space token:YES, equal space:no, space character:no, active character:no, implicit space:no.
space macro * : space token:no, equal space:no, space character:no, active character:no, implicit space:no.
active space : space token:YES, equal space:YES, space character:no, active character:YES, implicit space:YES.
par : space token:no, equal space:no, space character:no, active character:no, implicit space:no.
```

Comment: Why you use \expandafter in \if and \ifcat?

Comment: Yes, you are right. My code should be two `\expandafter` easier:). I'll correct it.

Comment: I tried to run your file in TeX and got this (I don't know how to use newline in comment, so  I used `\n`): \n `Runaway argument?` \n
`! Paragraph ended before \test was complete.` \n
`<to be read again>` \n
`                   \par ` \n
`l.37 par           : \test\par`

Comment: To your code I added this: `\def\stest#1{\expandafter\test\the#1\test}`, added `\test` to the end of parameter text of `\def\test` and then ran `\newtoks\t \t={ } \stest\t`. The result was: `space token:YES, equal space:YES, space character:YES, active character:no, implicit space:YES.` But this space is not implicit!

Comment: Yes, it was bad. I messed up implicit with explicit, sorry. Now, it is corrected.